# how to create a views tree with taxonomy term in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, treeview, view

I know the steps but am stuck because i don't the meaning of the terms which is used in below instructions.

```
Views Tree with Taxonomy Terms
Creating Taxonomy Terms

Create some Taxonomy terms with parent/child (hierarchical) relationships.
Creating the View

First, create a new term view using the fields row style / unformatted list of fields (it is important that the tree style not be chosen now). Then:

    Add relationship for taxonomy term: parent term
    Add field term id (do not use relationship) and exclude it from display
    Add field term id with relationship, exclude from display
    Add any fields you want to display, like term name, term description, etc...
    Change style / format plugin to Tree (Adjacency model)
    Set Main field to Term ID
    Set Parent field to Term ID with parent relationship
```

> I want to follow above steps, i have created the taxonomy term with
>   parent child relationships and then i create the view here i got
>   confuse becuase they mentioned **fields row style / unformatted list
>   of fields (it is important that the tree style not be chosen now).
>   Then:

**

```
Add relationship for taxonomy term: parent term
Add field term id (do not use relationship) and exclude it from display
Add field term id with relationship, exclude from display
Add any fields you want to display, like term name, term description, etc...
Change style / format plugin to Tree (Adjacency model)
Set Main field to Term ID
Set Parent field to Term ID with parent relationship
```

> i dont know where is taxonomy term when i clickk on advance there is
>   no taxonomy term : parent term please help me to out of this

Answer (score 0):

When you click on "advance" in the page detail of your view, you have the "Relationship" part : click on "Add" button and check "Taxonomy term: Parent term".
For the fields, you have a "Fields" part, also with an "Add" button.

It's pretty easy, everything is explained, it's a step by step instructions.

Comment: there is no taxonomy term. should i share my screen shot?

Comment: 1/ make sure that your taxonomy module is able.

2/ When you create your view, you must change the content type before save and edit :
Show "Taxonomy term" 
of type "All"
sorted by "Unsorted"
If you didn't create properly, you won't have the taxonomy term in your view search.

Comment: let me know for this i need to create the taxonomy term as well?

Comment: Well, at least one vocabulary, and a couple of terms.